Install MySQL errors temporary issue?
I am running the following on 23.10 on 7th May 2024.
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
[sudo] password for USER: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 is to be installed
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.23.10.1) but it is not installable
                Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.23.10.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

As can be seen it looks like there isn't a MYSQL version available for my Ubuntu version at this time. I have run the advice on answers such as this - Upgrade MySQL server issue which purge MySQL and reinstall but the error remains the same.
Q) Is there a way of installing mysql from a more reliable place / way so that its not quite as tied to the Ubuntu version or should I simply wait a few days and see if it works?

Does this answer your question? mysql-server-8.0 conflict, unable to install due to a conflict with "itself"

As per my answer I have read that and no it was a very different issue.

So after further investigation I found this answer:
mysql-server-8.0 conflict, unable to install due to a conflict with "itself"
However please be aware this removes any and every file with MySQL in its name and as I'm running on a local dev machine I didn't want PHP config files and things removed!!!
However I did noticed these two files in the result list which when removed then allowed me to do an install!
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list.distUpgrade
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
